asp.net mvc: How to loop through @Model.DataTable rows in javascript
My view uses a dataset as a model.
I need to loop through all the rows in the first table of the dataset in javascript, but can't get that to work.
    function GetData() {
                var Arr = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < @Model.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++) {
                    Arr.push({ x: ['@Model.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ProjTaskDateStart"]', '@Model.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ProjTaskDateEnd"]'], y: 'Task @Model.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ProjTaskNum"]', name: '@Model.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ProjTaskTitle"]', TaskStatus: '@Model.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ProjTaskTitle"]'})
                };

console.log(Arr);

             
    }


it's the javascript variable "i" that is not being read withing the Rows[i]. Totally understand why, but is there a way to get around it and still loop through the rows in javascript?
